# Java: Can't get JFrame to work

Tags: java, loops, jframe

I'm having a bit of trouble with a program I've been working on for a few days now. Basically what I'm trying to do is create a GUI to display user input to an HTML file. What I want to do is have my program loop over frame1's button, based on how many airport legs they have, in order to grab all of the users input: Airport name, Lat and Long. Any help is appreicated

```
package project4;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;



public class MainClass {

public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) { new MainClass();}

    // Fields
        private int legs;
        private double speed;
        private double totTime = 0;
        private double totDist = 0;
        private double lat;
        private double lng;
        private String name;
        Airport user;

    public MainClass()  {

        // Variable Declarations

        // Frame window 1 : Contains Legs and Speed
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Legs and Speed");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel labelLegs = new JLabel("Legs:");
        JLabel labelSpeed = new JLabel("Speed:");
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(5); // Leg field
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(5); // Speed field
        JButton button = new JButton("Ok");


        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Airport Name:");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Latitude:");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Longitude");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField tf4 = new JTextField(5);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Ok");

            // Add elements to panel and then to frame
            panel.add(labelLegs);
            panel.add(tf); // Leg field
            panel.add(labelSpeed);
            panel.add(tf1); // Speed field
            panel.add(button);
            frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        class legsAndSpeedListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                legs = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
                speed = Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        ActionListener listener = new legsAndSpeedListener();
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        // Arrays for Latitude and Longitude and Airport Name
        String[] airportName = new String[legs];
        double[] latitudeArr = new double[legs];
        double[] longitudeArr = new double[legs];




            panel1.add(label1);
            panel1.add(tf2);
            panel1.add(label2);
            panel1.add(tf3);
            panel1.add(label3);
            panel1.add(tf4);
            panel1.add(button1);
            frame1.add(panel1);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

            class portItinerary implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    name = tf2.getText();
                    lat = Double.parseDouble(tf3.getText());
                    lng = Double.parseDouble(tf4.getText());
                }
            }
            ActionListener listener1 = new portItinerary();
            button1.addActionListener(listener1);

            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < legs; i++)
        {
            latitudeArr[i] = lat;
            longitudeArr[i] = lng;
            airportName[i] = name;
        }
    }
}   





    package project4;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Airport extends MainClass {

    public static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 10800 / Math.PI;
    public static final double RAD = Math.PI / 180;

    // Fields
    public static double Lat;
    public static double Long;
    public static String ID;
    public static double Distance;
    public static int legs;

    public Airport()
    {

    }

    public void setWindow()
    {


    }




    // Mutators
    public static void setDistance(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
    {
        // Sin converter
        double distance1;
        double sinLat1 = lat1 * RAD;
        double sinLat2 = lat2 * RAD;

        // Cos converter
        double cosLat1 = lat1 * RAD;
        double cosLat2 = lat2 * RAD;
        double cosLong1 = long1 * RAD;
        double cosLong2 = long2 * RAD;


        // Calculation of the great circle distance based on two coordinates in nautical miles
        distance1 = (Math.sin(sinLat1) * Math.sin(sinLat2) + Math.cos(cosLat1) * Math.cos(cosLat2) * Math.cos((cosLong1 - cosLong2)));
        Distance = EARTH_RADIUS * Math.acos(distance1);
    }

    // Accessors
    public static double getLat() {return Lat;}
    public static double getDistance(){return Distance;}
    public static double getLong(){return Long;}
    public static String getID() {return ID;}

}
```

Comment: Save your self some trouble and use a `JTable`

Comment: Any reason why? Person experience I'm guessing? haha

Comment: I might be missing the point, but form the sounds of it, you have a dynamic number of legs

Comment: Yep, and I was using the user input for legs to determine how big my arrays were going to be and also how many times I would loop certain parts of the program

Comment: A JTable with a DefaultTableModel and such might be easiest to maintain a dynamically growing list of rows.

Comment: Would JTable still be recommended even if I'm outputting to an HTML file? I'm assuming it wouldn't matter but I'm just checkin

Comment: The input and output are two different things, collect the data from the user and use that to generate the output

Comment: Well you see, that's my problem. I'm able to collect the users 'legs' and 'speed' but when the program displays the next GUI to collect 'airport name, lat and long' it's not letting me store those values... furthermore because the 'airport name, lat, and long' is based off of the 'legs' entered, I need to second GUI to allow me someone loop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some suggestions, these are based on preference

- declare all variable together at the beginning of the constructor
- use variable names that unambiguous, ex: avoid frame, frame1, tf, tf1, tf2

  - it's difficult for others to understand your code
- It sounds like you are looking to use recursion for each leg, so I would create a new JFrame instance for each leg
- with that thought I believe its a good idea to create instances on the spot, when you need them rather them creating all of them ahead of time
- I would separate the two JFrames into their own classes
- I'm curious why the width, and height are static and final. I've never seen that before, if that was unintentional I would just leave them as final
- Also, the private Listener classes, I would recommend always starting classes with a capital letter, as far as I know this branches to private classes as well

### Submitted Code Edit

- As I suggested about using instances, when the user clicks 'ok'. An instance of the second JFrame window is created, rather then making it visible
- Since your code continues across different JFrames, there was a main class for the core code, another class for the legs/speed JFrame, and another class for the airport/lat/long JFrame
- I'm not too familiar with private classes, so I tried my best to avoid making it a confusing mess, please pardon any bad code
- After using a JFrame, the JFrame was disposed of, I recommend creating new instances over playing with the window visibility

  ```
          package airportproj;
      import java.awt.*;
      import java.awt.event.*;
      import java.util.*;
      import javax.swing.*;

      public class AirportProj {

          public static void main(String[] args) { new AirportProj();}

          // Fields
          private MainClass mainWindow;
          private LegClass legClass;
          private int legs, currentLeg;
          private double speed;
          private double totTime = 0;
          private double totDist = 0;
          private String[] airportNames;
          private double[] latitudes;
          private double[] longtitudes;
          Airport user;

          public AirportProj()  {
              class legsAndSpeedListener implements ActionListener
              {
                  @Override
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      legs = mainWindow.getLegs();
                      speed = mainWindow.getSpeed();
                      mainWindow.dispose();
                      airportNames= new String[legs];
                      latitudes = new double[legs];
                      longtitudes = new double[legs];
                      currentLeg = 0;
                      class PortItinerary implements ActionListener
                      {
                          @Override
                          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                              airportNames[currentLeg] = legClass.getAirportName();
                              latitudes[currentLeg] = legClass.getLatitude();
                              longtitudes[currentLeg] = legClass.getLongtitude();
                              legClass.dispose();
                              if (++currentLeg < legs) {
                                  legClass = new LegClass(new PortItinerary());
                              }else {
                                  doWhateverYouWantToDoNext();
                              }
                          }
                      }

                      legClass = new LegClass(new PortItinerary());
                  }
              }

              mainWindow = new MainClass(new legsAndSpeedListener());
          }

          public void doWhateverYouWantToDoNext() {
              for (int i = 0; i < legs; i ++) {
                  System.out.println("Airport Name: " + airportNames[i]);
                  System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitudes[i]);
                  System.out.println("Longtitude: " + longtitudes[i]);
              }
          }
      }   

      class MainClass extends JFrame {
          private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
          private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
          private JTextField legInput, speedInput;

          public MainClass(ActionListener listener) {
              // Frame window 1 : Contains Legs and Speed
              JPanel container = new JPanel();
              JLabel labelLegs = new JLabel("Legs:");
              JLabel labelSpeed = new JLabel("Speed:");
              legInput = new JTextField(5); // Leg field
              speedInput = new JTextField(5); // Speed field
              JButton button = new JButton("Ok");
              button.addActionListener(listener);

              setTitle("Legs and Speed");
              setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
              setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

              // Add elements to panel and then to frame
              container.add(labelLegs);
              container.add(legInput); // Leg field
              container.add(labelSpeed);
              container.add(speedInput); // Speed field
              container.add(button);
              add(container);
              setVisible(true);
          }

          public int getLegs() {
              return Integer.parseInt(legInput.getText());
          }

          public double getSpeed() {
              return Double.parseDouble(speedInput.getText());
          }
      }

      class LegClass extends JFrame {
          private String name;
          private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
          private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
          private JTextField airportInput, latitudeInput,longtitudeInput;

          public LegClass(ActionListener listener) {
              setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
              setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

              JLabel airportName = new JLabel("Airport Name:");
              JLabel latitude = new JLabel("Latitude:");
              JLabel longtitude = new JLabel("Longitude");
              JPanel container = new JPanel();
              airportInput = new JTextField(5);
              latitudeInput = new JTextField(5);
              longtitudeInput = new JTextField(5);
              JButton okay = new JButton("Ok");
              okay.addActionListener(listener);

              container.add(airportName);// airport
              container.add(airportInput);
              container.add(latitude);  // latitude
              container.add(latitudeInput);
              container.add(longtitude);   // longtitude
              container.add(longtitudeInput);
              container.add(okay);
              add(container);

              setVisible(true);
          }

          public String getAirportName() {
              return airportInput.getText();
          }

          public double getLatitude() {
              return Double.parseDouble(latitudeInput.getText());
          }

          public double getLongtitude() {
              return Double.parseDouble(longtitudeInput.getText());
          }
      }
  ```
- I didn't touch the airport class, I hope this helps! A lot of the code style and ways to a means are my preference and don't feel you need to copy anything exactly

Comment: Hey man sorry for the late reply, It was late last night and I had to get to bed. Your code looks good! thanks for help, ofc I made a couple modifications to fit my needs but overall it worked. I had been trying to figure out how to have JFrame windows come up based off of the users input and it never occured to me to create new instances of them as you did. Thanks again